# What would be the best solution for having a mobile application store/retrieve/update data

Tags: database, mobile-phones

I'm developing a web based application built on codeigniter which will also have a mobile application(blackberry, iphone, android etc.). The web application will be connecting to a (mysql) database to store/retrieve/update data. I would like to know what would be the best solution for having a mobile application store/retrieve/update data.

Taking into consideration performance, flexibility, Security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your device no different than if it was a browser.  The are both clients.  All devices (well at least Android and iOS) provide you with ways to make xhr requests, just like your browser does.  So you need an API on your server that your device will use to get the data.  Note that if your application does not already have an API, you will need to develop one.